# Matrix entry notation and plane coordinate notation

Tags: notation, definition, coordinate-systems, education, index-notation

Let $A$ be an $m \times n$ matrix, and $a_{ij}$ a matrix entry.

Usually the index $i$ indicates the row and $j$ the column of the matrix.

So changing the index $i$ makes you move in the $vertical$ direction and changing the index $j$ makes you move in the $horizontal$ direction through the matrix.

I noticed that this is exactly the other way around for how we use coordinates in the cartesian-plane, where we have a point in the plane $p = (x,y)$, and by changing the first entry we move in the $horizontal$ diretion and by changing the second entry we move in the $vertical$ direction.

I know that in a sense they are just arbitrary agreements so we can communicate about it, but I thought that maybe someone has some deeper inside about why this is the case or is it just a coincidence? And wouldn't you agree that changing $i$ to be the column and $j$ to be the row be more natural?

Comment: Additionally, note that _increasing_ $i$ will make us move _downwards_, which also goes against common coordinate system conventions.

Comment: it really is just an arbitrary agreement. Nothing deep about this. Another arbitrary piece of agreement: in special relativity, one draws 'spacetime diagrams' in which the time coordinate $t$ is drawn vertically while the space coordinate $x$ is drawn horizontally; in complete opposition to how things are done, I'd say in any single/multivariabel calculus course.

Comment: When I look at a matrix I think of the rows going top to bottom. Rotate the (x, y) axes clockwise through 90 degrees.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of the reason of the difference, but I agree that unifying it may be better.

Indeed, this is quite confusing in some applications like when you are trying to plot a matrix as heatmap vs showing a matrix as digital image, the first index (row index) will become the negative y coordinate on image plane, and column index becomes the positive x coordinate... It's easy to implement this wrong and get the image upsidedown flipped or transposed. This is caused by the different convention of the two fields...